# Problems in installing ubuntu 20.04.6 in dell precision workstation

Tags: system-installation, dell, codecs

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.6 in a Dell precision workstation. In the "try mode" everything was fine, net connection, YouTube videos etc... However after the installation, after remove the pendrive and restart, I received the following messages:

```
/dev/nvmeOn1p2: clean, 198503/62480384 files , 70441866/249919744 blokcs
[    6.926246]
[    6.994841]   snd_hda_intel 0000:53:00.4: no codecs found!
[    7.603964]   dell_smm_hwmon: unable to get SMM Dell signature
```

And then, a black screen with a blinking underscore.

Any suggestion how to solve the problem?